# Angular 2 HTTP client weird behaviour

Tags: http, angular, get, angular2-services

So currently i'm trying out an angular2 app but i'm experiencing a weird reaction when i use the http.get(url).

```
let url = http://localhost/site/get/data?id='+id;
return this._http.get(url).map(
      res => res.json()
```

The problem is when i use localhost for testing it works for my laptop, but when i switch it to my ip (192.168.1.xx).

```
let url = http://192.168.1.xx/site/get/data?id='+id;
return this._http.get(url).map(
      res => res.json()
```

It stops giving me results and gives me the empty list response in my code.

But the strange part is that while it doesn't locally work on my PC if i use it on another device with the 192.168.1.xx IP it gives me correct results.

i even manually try using the get statement on both my browser locally and my postman, with both giving me correct results.

Anyone knows why this issue is happening with the address switch?

Comment: Your browser's console does not log any errors or warnings?

Comment: @Matt Nothing at all, it just behaves as if there is no connection to the server.

Comment: @Matt well i've kinda misunderstood you, i'm adding the javascript errors, i thought any unusual errors

Comment: It could be so many reasons. The first things that come to my mind are CORS issues (which your browser would tell you about) or local firewall rules that block the request.